# Как сделать свой видеоплеер проигрывателем по умолчанию и чтоб он открывал переданый ему при старте адрес видеофайла?

Tags: android, videoview

В интернете есть много информации о том как осуществить проигрывание видео, но я так и не нашел как сделать так чтоб плеер проигрывал переданный ему на старте адрес видеофайла, или например, когда в браузере жмешь кнопку плей, на каком ни будь видео, чтоб твой плеер получал это видео. Подскажите пожалуйста ресурс или решение.

Answer (score 1):

Прописываете в манифесте что то типа такого:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.player.MainPlayerActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:mimeType="video/*"  />
        <data android:mimeType="application/mp4*" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/mpeg*" />

        <data android:pathPattern=".*mpg" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*MPG" />

        <data android:pathPattern=".*mpeg" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*MPEG" />

        <data android:pathPattern=".*avi" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*AVI" />

        <data android:pathPattern=".*mp4" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*MP4" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

И будете ловить этой активити интенты на проигрывание видео в указанных форматах.

Comment: Всеравно есть проблема с тем что, на пример, chrome запускает встроеный видеолпеер. Получается что из мобильного браузера перенаправление не получится. А возможен ли сценарий ,если открыть тот же chrome методом startActivityForResult и после тапа по кнопке Play в этом же браузере, передать ресурс видео в свое приложение?

Comment: Ну как поступает хром при клике на видео, одному ему известно. Если он не вызывает Intent с каким нибудь Action, то перехватить это нельзя.